# Does the st_ino field of struct stat give information about permissions?

Tags: file, unix, permissions

Does `st_ino` give us any information about permission settings of a file? If yes how?
I thought only `st_gid`, `st_uid` and similar data members stored information related to permissions.

Answer (score 2):

`st_ino` is just the inode number - it is an `ino_t` which is typedef'd and/or #defined in a system, filesystem, and compiler implementation specific way, but is generally an `int`, `long`, or `int64`.

It contains no information about permissions.